# Linking errors when building for simulator but not device

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, ios-simulator

I am building my application for iPhone Simulator. I am getting the following error:

> missing required architecture i386 in file

The issue is occurring for a static library I have included in the project. It says "could not resolve symbols during linking for methods available in static library".

But if I change the mode to "Device" and build and run in the device, the application build succeeds and it works fine on the device.

How come the build for simulator is not working while the device build does?

Comment: [This question probably has all the info you're looking for](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4917752/115730)