# AVFoundation framework error

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get rid of the warning “file was built for unsupported file format” when linking with a static library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917752/how-to-get-rid-of-the-warning-file-was-built-for-unsupported-file-format-when)

I write `#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>` in my code but when i compile it gives the following error: 'AVFoundation/AVAsset.h' file not found
Also I got following warning:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks//AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (armv7)
```

Kindly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the AVFoundation framework to your target.
In Xcode select your Project, then select your target, click on "Build Phases" and expand "Link Binary with Libraries". Then click on the "+" and search for AVFoundation, add it and you should be good to go.

Comment: Yes I have already added this

Answer (score 0):

Scratch my previous answer, I found a more likely solution.

I believe that when you added the framework to your project you copied it into your project instead of simply linking it to the project. You should remove the framework from the project, by deleting ONLY if necessary. Then add the framework again.

If you are adding it by dragging and dropping from Finder, be sure to uncheck the "copy" checkbox when coping to Xcode.

Comment: I deleted and add it again. but still doesn't work